# Acces to a table inside a table Angular

Tags: angular, angular-material

I am new to Angular, I have declared a table and inside it another table I want to have access to its data. you can find what I have done so far below

### component.ts

```js
export interface Step {
      cols: number;
      rows: number;
      text: string;
      opt1: any[];
      opt2: any[];
}
        
export class FeaturesComponent {
    stepsTwo: Step[] = [
    {text: 'Provider', cols: 1, rows: 1, opt1: [{name: 'AWS', check:false}], opt2: [{name: 'Azure', check: false}]},
    {text: 'Architecture', cols: 1, rows: 1, opt1: [{name: 'ECS', check:false }], opt2: [{name: 'Lambda', check: false}]},    
  ];
}
```

### component.html

```html
<mat-grid-list cols="3" rowHeight="3:3">
               <mat-grid-tile
                 *ngFor="let step of stepsTwo"
                 [colspan]="step.cols"
                 [rowspan]="step.rows"
                 [style.background]="step.color">
                 <mat-card class="feature-card">
                    <mat-card-title   >
                       {{step.text}}
                    </mat-card-title>
                    <mat-card-content >
                      <p><button mat-raised-button >{{ step.opt1.name }}</button></p>
                      <p><button mat-raised-button >{{ step.opt2.name }}</button></p>
                   </mat-card-content>
                 </mat-card>
               </mat-grid-tile>
</mat-grid-list>
```

so I didn't succeed to get the name.

The idea is that I want to be give the right to select one button in each card, the button gets colored the check value resets to true and saves the name in an array or anything and export it as json which, I don't know how to do. the picture below will explain better.

[example_image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Wyte5.png)

Answer (score 1):

On a first look and based on your source structure which look like so : `{text: 'Provider', cols: 1, rows: 1, opt1: [{name: 'AWS', check:false}], opt2: [{name: 'Azure', check: false}]}` i see that `opt1` and `opt2` are arrays that contain single object, so the way to show the name will be `opt1[0].name`.

```html
<mat-grid-list cols="3" rowHeight="3:3">
             <mat-grid-tile
             *ngFor="let step of stepsTwo; let i = index"
             [colspan]="step.cols"
             [rowspan]="step.rows"
             [style.background]="step.color">
                <mat-card class="feature-card">
                    <mat-card-title   >
                        {{step.text}}
                    </mat-card-title>
                    <mat-card-content >
                        <p><button mat-raised-button (click)="addToSelection(i, 'opt1')">{{ step.opt1[0].name }}</button></p>
                        <p><button mat-raised-button (click)="addToSelection(i, 'opt2')">{{ step.opt2[0].name }}</button></p>
                    </mat-card-content>
                </mat-card>
                </mat-grid-title>
</mat-frid-list>
```

```js
export interface Step {
      cols: number;
      rows: number;
      text: string;
      opt1: any[];
      opt2: any[];
}
    
export class FeaturesComponent {
    stepsTwo: Step[] = [
    {text: 'Provider', cols: 1, rows: 1, opt1: [{name: 'AWS', check:false}], opt2: [{name: 'Azure', check: false}]},
    {text: 'Architecture', cols: 1, rows: 1, opt1: [{name: 'ECS', check:false }], opt2: [{name: 'Lambda', check: false}]},    
  ];
  
  addToSelection(stepIdx, opt){
    if(opt === 'opt1'){
        this.stepsTwo[idx]['opt1'].check = !this.stepsTwo[idx]['opt1'].check
        this.stepsTwo[idx]['opt2'].check = !this.stepsTwo[idx]['opt1'].check
    }else{
        this.stepsTwo[idx]['opt2'].check = !this.stepsTwo[idx]['opt2'].check
        this.stepsTwo[idx]['opt1'].check = !this.stepsTwo[idx]['opt2'].check
    }
  }
}
```

About storing the selections, the thing that you want to do is toggle the chek inside your `Step` items which can be achieved as seen in the example.

However, even if the example above works fine, I think that you should change your approach of solving this problem. I would suggest if possible a data structure that looks more like this:

```js
export interface Step {
      cols: number;
      rows: number;
      text: string;
      options: any[];
}

export class FeaturesComponent {
    stepsTwo: Step[] = [
    {text: 'Provider', cols: 1, rows: 1, options: [{name: 'AWS'}, {name: 'Azure'}]},
    {text: 'Architecture', cols: 1, rows: 1, options: [{name: 'ECS'}, {name: 'Lambda'}]},    
  ];
  
  selectedProvider = null;
  selectedArchitecture = null;
  

  addToSelection(stepIdx, opt){
    if(stepIdx === 0){
    this.selectedProvider = opt;
    }else{
    this.selectedArchtecture = opt;
    }
  }
}
```

The reason that im suggesting this approach is because often times when we have a problem that is related to toggling stuff we end in a situations where we are toggling the wrong stiff (especially when we are toggling stuff by reference) so my recommendation is to explicitly state in a separate field which item has been selected without modifing the initial table data source.

** EDIT

In order for the second strucure to work right your template should look like this. The main difference is that we are passing to the `addToSelection` function reference to the option object instead of string.

```html
<mat-grid-list cols="3" rowHeight="3:3">
             <mat-grid-tile
             *ngFor="let step of stepsTwo; let i = index"
             [colspan]="step.cols"
             [rowspan]="step.rows"
             [style.background]="step.color">
                <mat-card class="feature-card">
                    <mat-card-title   >
                        {{step.text}}
                    </mat-card-title>
                    <mat-card-content >
                        <button *ngFor"let option of options;" mat-raised-button (click)="addToSelection(i, option)">{{ option.name }}</button>
                    </mat-card-content>
                </mat-card>
                </mat-grid-title>
</mat-frid-list>
```

Here is live demo at [StackBlitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/tablge-grid-question?file=src/app/grid-list-dynamic-example.html)

Comment: Thank you for your solution it's been usefull, i choosed to go with your proposition for the data structure. the only problem I had is when I wanted to test the value of opt using console.log(selectedArchetecture) I had opt as a result and not the real names in the console am using firefox

Comment: @Claudyu look below the edit, you need to do also some changes inside the template, instead of passing the string `opt` you should pass reference to the option object.

Comment: thanks for the reply, I have tried this alreaady but when i use the second *ngFor it does not work

Comment: @Claudyu look at the stackblitz example that i had added

Comment: It was exactly what i wanted, thank you so much !